# How to attach an existing rbac role to an Azure VM using Terraform?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, terraform, rbac

I'm creating an Azure Virtual Machine using Terraform. But I don't know how to attach an existing rbac role to it. Is there a way to do this without creating a separate resource for role definition/attachment?
If separate resource needed how to do it knowing only the rbac role name?

Comment: did you check this already ? https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/role_assignment.html

Answer (score 2):

From your comment, you want to assign an RBAC role to a user with terraform. You can do it in two steps:

**step1**: Use this data source to access information about an existing Role Definition referring to [this](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_definition).

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "primary" {}  # access an existing subscription


data "azurerm_role_definition" "custom" {  # access an existing custom role via role_definition_id
  role_definition_id = "${azurerm_role_definition.custom.role_definition_id}"
  scope              = "${data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id}"              # /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
}

data "azurerm_role_definition" "custom-byname" { # access an existing custom role via name
  name  = "${azurerm_role_definition.custom.name}"
  scope = "${data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id}"
}

data "azurerm_builtin_role_definition" "builtin" { # access an existing builtin role
  name = "Contributor"
}
```

**step2**: Assign the role to a specific Azure AD user. For example, if you want to assign this role to a user at the resource group level, that is to define the scope with the resource group ID. You should have an existing resource group. You can create it with `resource "azurerm_resource_group"` block or `data "azurerm_resource_group"`, then assigns a given Principal (User or Application) to a given Role with [azurerm_role_assignment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/role_assignment.html).

Example Usage (using a built-in Role)

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "primary" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "myrg" {
  name     = "myrg"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "test" {
  scope                = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.id}"
  role_definition_name = "Reader" # or "${data.azurerm_role_definition.custom-byname.name}"
  principal_id         = "xxxx"
}
```

The `principal_id` is the `Object ID` of the user. You can find it via navigate to the Azure Active Directory in the portal -> Users -> search by the user principal name(email address in your case). You could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58916411/how-to-add-virtual-machine-user-login-roles-to-a-list-of-users-by-terraform).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for I believe is the `azurerm_role_definition` data source, which allows you to import an already existing role definition into terraform.

See documentation [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/role_definition.html).

Example:

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "primary" {}

data "azurerm_role_definition" "my_role" {
  ### Specify either role_definition_id or name of the existing role
  # role_definition_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  # name               = "MyRoleDefinition"

  scope = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
}
```

To assign this role to, for example, a resource group `my_rg`, set the scope to the resource group id:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "my_rg" {
  name     = "myRG"
  location = "West US"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "client_config" {}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "my_role_assignment" {
  scope              = azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.id
  role_definition_id = data.azurerm_role_definition.my_role.id
  principal_id       = data.azurerm_client_config.client_config.service_principal_object_id
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how i can attach role at the resource group level and vm level? In the above code how i can do it?  Basically i need to create a resource group and attach role and users to it.

Comment: I extended the example. Have a look at the terraform documentation, because it's really quite good: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/role_assignment.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response....How is principal_id defined here? What is client_config? How can i add a user to this particular role?

Comment: Sorry, don't have time to help you further - but good news is there's plenty of stuff out there to answer your questions. Also terraform documentation has alot of examples. If this answer has pointed you in the right direction, feel free to accept it.